# How to label percentage values inside stacked bar plot using R-base

Tags: r

I am new to R. I would like others to please explain to me how to add absolute values inside the individual stacked bars in a consistent way using the basic R plotting function (R base). I tried to plot a stacked bar graph using R base but the values appear in an inconsistent/illogical way in such a way that its supposed to be 100% for each village but they don't sum up to 100%.
Here is the data that am working on:

```
Village     100          200    300 400     500
Male    68.33333      53.33333   70 70      61.66667
Female  31.66667      46.66667   30 30      38.33333
```

In summary, there are five villages and the data showing the head of household interviewed by sex.

I have used the following command towards plotting the graph:

```
barplot(mydata,col=c("yellow","green")
x<-barplot(mydata,col=c("yellow","green")
text(x,mydata,labels=mydata,pos=3,offset=.5)
```

Please help to allocate the correct values in each bar
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to compute the heights using `cumsum`. Something like this :

```
heights =c(cumsum(dat[,1])-dat[,1]/2,cumsum(dat[,2])-dat[,2]/2),
```

I assume you data is, but the same method can be applied to the translate also,

```
 dat
        Male   Female
100 68.33333 31.66667
200 53.33333 46.66667
300 70.00000 30.00000
400 70.00000 30.00000
500 61.66667 38.33333
```

For example I do this:

```
midpts <- barplot(dat,col=rainbow(5),beside=F)
legend(2, 320, rownames(dat), cex=1, angle = c(135, 45),  fill =rainbow(5))
text(x= rep(midpts,each=5),
y =c(cumsum(dat[,1])-dat[,1]/2,cumsum(dat[,2])-dat[,2]/2),
label = round(unlist(dat),2),cex=1.2)
```

[image]